# encrypting excel workbook sheet with python

Tags: python, excel, encryption, openpyxl, win32com

I'm currently implementing a tool to automise parts of my daily work. Therefore I need to create a python tool which creates an excel-file (workbook) with several informations and encrypts the sheets of the file.
The first part which creates the file and fills it with the data works perfectly.

But the encryption doesn't work at all.
I'm using win32com, win32com.client and openpyxl. The workbook hast two different sheets, named "1" and "2".

My Workbook:

```
import win32com.client
import os, sys, win32com, os.path, time

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(reading_path) ####this is the path where the file is stored
sheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
```

So I searched through other topics and got the following:

```
import openpyxl    
sheet.protection.set_password('test') 
sheet.save(saving_path)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work... My shell response an AttributeError. In Detail:

```
AttributeError: <unknown>.set_password
```

Does someone knows another way how to encrypt just the pages in excel with python?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by "encrypting the sheet" as the `openpyxl` code you refer to has nothing to do with encryption; see the warning in [the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html). Excel does support encryption of entire workbooks though, but that appears to be different from what you want.

In any case, your code fails because the `sheet` you get from `win32com` is a wildly different beast than what `openpyxl` expects. For example, `sheet` being based on COM requires an Excel process to run for manipulation to be possible, while `openpyxl` does not even require Excel to be available on the host machine.

Now in your particular case, you do not actually need `openpyxl` (although you might find that using it over `win32com` has plenty of benefits), and you could stay entirely within COM. As such, adding password protection is possible through [`Worksheet.Protect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel) which in your case would boil down to simply running

```
sheet.Protect('test')
```